# Mongodb. Find documents by key from other collection

Tags: mongodb

mongodb:

```
#Authors collection
db.authors.insert({name: 'Kobo', birthday: '1860', country: 'jp', tags: ['japan', 'avant-garde', 'screen', 'Akutagawa Prize']})
db.authors.insert({name: 'Sartr', birthday: '1905', country: 'fr', tags: [...]})
db.authors.insert({name: 'Braun', birthday: '1913', country: 'us', tags: [...]}
...

#Books collection
db.books.insert({title: 'book1', author: 'Kobo', year :''});
db.books.insert({title: 'book2', author: 'Sartr', year :''});
db.books.insert({title: 'book3', author: 'author', year :''});
...
```

Autor tags are regularly added to the collection Authors.
Using book tags  is not considered in this question.

Need to find all the books in which the author has a certain tag. Such as 'avant-garde'. 
What is the most effective way to do this?
How to do it in pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB does not support joins.  So, with the data model you have, you'll have to break it down into 2 queries:

1. Query the authors collection to get list of all authors that have a certain tag
2. Query the books collection using the results from Step 1 to get list of books

If your data was modeled using embedded documents, i.e., either embedding `authors` inside `books` or the other way around, you can get the results in one query.

Comment: Authors will assume 10000 and 10 million books. It is a working situation for the mongodb or the search will approach infinity? As I understand it will be 10000 times 10000000 or 100 000 000 000 comparison operation

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly.  If your application will mostly access or retrieve books, then you should consider embedding authors inside books, although authors will be redundant.  I would suggest you to read up on [data modeling concepts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) for MongoDB, as it's quite different from modeling for RDBMS.  By embedding, you'll not need a join in the first place.  But if your use case is such that embedding is not feasible, but you'll have to do a lot of joins, then may be MongoDB is not the right database for your use case?